# Measuring Photosynthetically Active Radiation with inexpensive sensors

Tags: plant-health

I am looking to read the Photosynthetically Active Radiation in my grow area and I was curious if there is a way to do this without a PAR sensor?  Is there a way I can calculate PAR from other sensors like a photosensor or something along those lines?  Any advice on how to calculate PAR using something like an Arduino and some inexpensive sensors would be amazing!

Comment: How precise do you want to know the PAR to? Some manufacturers publish the spectrographic analysis of their products, or you can find approximate ones on the internet - eg. for tungsten lightbulbs or cool white cfl tubes.

Comment: I feel like I would like it to be somewhat accurate or there probably is little point in measuring it at all.  I have heard of people measuring PAR using LED's but I'm not sure how accurate or reliable the readings are... there seems to be much debate on the idea of using LEDs to measure PAR